# How to deploy retrained tensor flow model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have retrained image classification (poet) tensor flow model, and it's working fine. Now, i want to get it deployed on the google cloud platform, saw some links but not getting step by step doc which explains how retrained mode can be deployed with my own custom data (which is shelf filled with products). So, can you please provide any doc which explains the deployment process.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#4

Thanks
Amit